MQTT Error. Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt"
Currently I am using Local Mosquitto Broker to run my project. This is the link "https://github.com/Infineon/mtb-example-wifi-mqtt-radar-presence". The problem is when I am doing the Setting up the MQTT broker, Local Mosquitto Broker. I think the problems maybe between step 3 and 4.
The error shown like this:
1712297140: mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
1712297140: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1712297140: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1712297140: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1712297140: Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt".
1712297140: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
1712297140: OpenSSL Error[1]: error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file
1712297140: OpenSSL Error[2]: error:05880002:x509 certificate routines::system lib

mosquitto.conf
cafile C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt
keyfile C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\server.key
certfile C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\server.crt

I have tried many possibility of solution, but it still error. Anybody expert with this ?
Actually I dont found many solutions in the Internet. So most of my solution is refer to the ChatGPT Gemini, and Claude. and I expecting that there is no error, and my MQTT can run

Wrap the paths in quotes

Also edit the question to include the content of the car.crt
